# How to tell whether KeyboardEvent.key is a printable character or control character?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a keypress event which executes special functions for certain control characters, but inserts any printable character into a string.

```
this.handle_keypress = function(event) {
    let callback = this.control_function[event.key];
    if(callback) {
        callback.bind(this)(event);
    }
    else {
        this.myText += event.key;
    }
}

this.element.addEventListener('keypress', this.handle_keypress.bind(this));
```

But this will insert the text for unmapped control characters into my string (e.g. 'LeftArrow' or 'Backspace'). How can I tell which characters are printable characters and which are control characters?

Back in the day, I would use event.which or event.charCode, but these are marked as deprecated now.

I cannot use the input event, as far as I know, because I am not typing into a textarea or input field.

I'm running this in Firefox.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out the documentation for Properties of KeyboardEvent on MDN page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

For KeyboardEvent.keyCode, they mention:

> This attribute is deprecated; you should use KeyboardEvent.key
>   instead, if available.

For KeyboardEvent.charCode, they mention:

> Warning: This attribute is deprecated; you should use
>   KeyboardEvent.key instead, if available.

So basically "charCode" and "keyCode" have been replaced by simply "code" and "key".

Also, to identify the control characters and avoid printing them, you can try:

1. Create an array of neglected characters

   ```
   var unsupportedKeyCharacters = ["Shift", "Escape", "ArrowUp", "ArrowDown", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "Enter"];
   ```
2. Call the function to check if entered character is printable

   ```
       var isSupportedKey = function (keyCharacter) {
       var isKeySupported = false;
       var unsupportedKeyCharacters = ["Shift", "Escape", "ArrowUp", "ArrowDown", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "Enter"];
       for (var i = 0; i < unsupportedKeyCharacters.length; i++) {
           if (unsupportedKeyCharacters[i] === keyCharacter) {
               isKeySupported = false;
               break;
           }
       }
       return isKeySupported;
   }
   ```
3. Call the function to validate input

Comment: KeyboardEvent.code isn't quite what I need because it won't distinguish between 'A' and 'a', for example. Making a list of unsupported keys isn't the cleanest solution, but I'll keep it in mind if nothing nicer pops up, thank you!

Comment: I agree. Definitely not a convenient way, albeit the only solution I could find. If this manages to solve your problem, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I feel Kernel's answer is better as it could be difficult to keep track of non printable chars. Like this answer doesn't contain 'Meta' for command key in Mac OS.

Answer (score 3):

There's no immediately way to determine if `event.key` is a control character.
But given that:

- the names of control characters are all currently multiple chars long (e.g., "Escape") and only contain letters and numbers
- the length of ASCII characters is 1
- non-ASCII characters contain bytes outside the range of [a-zA-Z]

You can make a code to decide between either or:

```
var letters = [];

elm.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if(e.key.length == 1 || (e.key.length > 1 && /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(e.key))) {
    letters.push(e.key);

  } else if(e.key == "Spacebar") {
    letters.push(" ");
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: All these answers work for specific cases only, and it baffles me there is no supported way to do it... Rather they deprecate everything (even the keypress event) that used to do it. Just an example for this specific answer: not only ASCII characters are printable. There are lots of others on my keyboard, for example 'ú', 'ű', 'é', 'Í'.